# Change action menu icon in MUI datagrid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

I am using the community version of `@mui/x-data-grid`.

I have this column defintion:

```js
const columns = [
  {
    field: "actions",
    type: "actions",
    width: 100,
    getActions: (cell) => [
      <GridActionsCellItem
        label={strings.addSome}
        onClick={() => openAddModal(cell.row)}
        showInMenu
      />,
      <GridActionsCellItem
        label={strings.pickSome}
        onClick={() => openPickModal(cell.row)}
        showInMenu
      />,
      <GridActionsCellItem
        label={strings.remove}
        onClick={() => openRemoveModal(cell.row)}
        showInMenu
      />,
      <GridActionsCellItem
        label={strings.modifyQty}
        onClick={renderComingSoon}
        showInMenu
      />,
    ],
  },
];
```

This result in the following output:

[image]

I want to change the display icon for the action menu button, is there an option to do si?

Answer (score 1):

The `moreActionsIcon` slot is needed. To show horizontal dots instead of vertical and with a smaller size, this worked. (`MUI DataGrid v5.12.1`)

```
import MoreHorizRoundedIcon from '@mui/icons-material/MoreHorizRounded'


    function CustomActionsIcon () {
      return (
        <MoreHorizRoundedIcon sx={{ fontSize: 25 }} />
      )
    }
    
    <DataGrid
        components={{
            MoreActionsIcon: CustomActionsIcon
         }}
```

[image: Horizontal dots instead of vertical!]

Answer (score 0):

`DataGrid` component has `components` prop, which allows to replace almost any default component with custom one. I'm pretty sure that you need `BaseButton` to be like

```
const CustomButton = () => (
    <IconButton>
        <AnyIconFromMUIIconSet />
    </IconButton>
);

<DataGrid
    components: {
        BaseButton: CustomButton
    }
    // rest of your props
```

For more information about Slots please refer [to DataGrid API](https://mui.com/x/api/data-grid/data-grid/#slots).